# A simple way of parsing a program arguments

Tags: haskell

I've seen some approaches about parsing program arguments. They seem to be too complicated. I need a **simple** solution. But I also want to be able (preferably, not necessarily) to refer to the arguments by name. So if a command like looks like this:

```
./MyApp --arg1Name arg1Value --arg2Name arg2Value
```

then I'd like to treat them as `args["arg1Name"]` and `args["arg2Name"]` to get their values. I know that's not a valid Haskell code, though. What I have now is not much:

```
main = do
  [args] <- getArgs
```

I repeat, I'd like a simple solution, preferably without involving any third-party haskell libraries.

Comment: Not so easy. Some arguments are meant to be followed by values and others are not, and the arguments parsing code needs to know which is which.

Comment: @n.m., in my cause all the argument followed by the values.

Comment: Try `parse xs = Data.Map.fromList . filter ((== "--") . take 2 . fst) $ zip xs (tail xs)`. No syntax error checks but hey, what do you want from a one-liner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just parsing them in pairs and adding them to a map:

```
simpleArgsMap :: [String] -> Map String String
simpleArgsMap [] = Map.empty
simpleArgsMap (('-':'-':name):value:rest)
    = Map.insert name value (simpleArgsMap rest)
simpleArgsMap xs = error $ "Couldn't parse arguments: " ++ show xs
```

A simple wrapper program to show this working:

```
module Args where

import System.Environment ( getArgs )
import Control.Applicative ( (<$>) )

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Map ( Map )

main = do
  argsMap <- simpleArgsMap <$> getArgs
  print $ Map.lookup "foo" argsMap
```

Comment: is there a necessity to import Map 2 times? import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Map ( Map )`?

Comment: It's a fairly standard pattern. You can leave out `import Data.Map ( Map )` but then you have to refer to the type as `Map.Map`.

Comment: by the way, in terms of naming convention, is the space between Map and the braces necessary `import Data.Map ( Map ) `, is this acceptable `import Data.Map(Map)` in the eyes of **most** haskell developers?

Comment: Yes, it's fine, and probably more normal actually - I just happen to mainly work on a codebase (Darcs) that uses the spaces so I default to including them.

Answer (score 5):

[`optparse-applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) is great for argument parsing, and very easy to use! Writing your own argument parser will be *much* more difficult to get right, change, extend, or otherwise manage than if you take 10 minutes to write a parser with `optparse-applicative`.

Start by importing the `Options.Applicative` module.

```
import Options.Applicative
```

Next create a data type for your command-line configuration.

```
data Configuration = Configuration
                     { foo :: String
                     , bar :: Int
                     }
```

Now for the workhorse, we create a parser by using the combinators exported from `optparse-applicative`. Read the documentation on [`Options.Applicative.Builder`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.9.0/docs/Options-Applicative-Builder.html) for the full experience.

```
configuration :: Parser Configuration
configuration = Configuration
            <$> strOption
                ( long "foo"
               <> metavar "ARG1"
                )
            <*> option
                ( long "bar"
               <> metavar "ARG2"
                )
```

Now we can execute our `Parser Configuration` in an `IO` action to get at our command-line data.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
          config <- execParser (info configuration fullDesc)
          putStrLn (show (bar config) ++ foo config)
```

And we're done! You can easily extend this parser to support a `--help` argument to print out usage documentation (make a new parser with `helper <*> configuration` and pass it to `info`), you can add default values for certain arguments (include a `<> value "default"` clause in the arguments to `strOption` or `option`), you can support flags, or sub-parsers or generate tab-completion data.

Libraries are a force multiplier! The investment you make in learning the basics of a good library will pay dividends in what you're able to accomplish, and tasks will often be easier (and quicker!) with the proper tool than with a "fast" solution thrown together out of duct tape.

Comment: The `option` now needs an Option Reader. `auto` offers such functionality and the according line has to be changed as follows:
    `<*> option`
to
    `<*> option auto`