# How to use Int with the optparse-applicative inside a data constructor?

Tags: haskell

I would like to use the [optparse-applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) package to add command line arguments to my program.

The program requires different types of parameters (`String` and `Int`). To keep it simple, I would like to only have one data type to hold all my settings like this:

```
data Configuration = Configuration
                    { foo :: String
                    , bar :: Int
                    }
```

I found one way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24647370/1004795) to do this. But unfortunately it seems that the functions have changed.

Here is a minimal (not) working example of what I would like to do:

```
module Main where

import Options.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader

data Configuration = Configuration
                    { foo :: String
                    , bar :: Int
                    }

configuration :: Parser Configuration
configuration = Configuration
    <$> strOption
        ( long "foo"
       <> metavar "ARG1"
        )
    <*> option
        ( long "bar"
       <> metavar "ARG2"
       )

main :: IO ()
main = do
    config <- execParser (info configuration fullDesc)
    putStrLn (show (bar config) ++ foo config)
```

Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to implement a `intOption` similar to the `strOption`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is tell option to use the *auto* reader, as in this fragment of code:

```
configuration :: Parser Configuration
configuration = Configuration
    <$> strOption
        ( long "foo"
        <> metavar "ARG1"
        )
    <*> option auto
        ( long "bar"
        <> metavar "ARG2"
        )
```

The difference between strOption and option, is that strOption assumes a String return type, while option can be configured to use custom readers. The *auto* reader assumes a *Read* instance for the return type.

There is good documentation in the [OptParse applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) Hackage page.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Must have missed that option in the documentation.